# Make a disabled TextFormField scrollable

Tags: flutter, textformfield

To put it simple, I have this:

```dart
TextFormField (
  enabled: false,
  readOnly: false,
  initialValue: 'lorem\nipsum\ndolor\nsit\namet\nconsectetur\nadipiscing\nelit\nsed',
  minLines: 5,
  maxLines: 5,
),
```

This input has each of the 5 first words of the lorem ipsum visible, and the rest of them below, which should be accessible using the scroll.

However, if the input is set to `enabled: false`, the input cannot be scrolled anymore, thus making the full text not visible.

Using the `readOnly` is not an option neither, since it does not provide the desired user experience because, for instance, the input is clickable.

A multiline input being scrollable is something that HTML already does when using `<textarea disabled>`, so why wouldn't Flutter?

Is there a way to make the `TextFormField` scrollable, so the hidden text can be seen?

Comment: Try use maxLine to 1

Comment: @AnanAlfred thanks for the response, but that wouldn't work, only aggravate the problem. The user would then only see one word, when in fact there are many more on the lines below.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot about how it is looking right now?

Answer (score 1):

try using with decoration

```
TextFormField(
          enabled: true,
          readOnly: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
          initialValue: 'lorem\nipsum\ndolor\nsit\namet\nconsectetur\nadipiscing\nelit\nsed\ndasd\ndasdas',
          minLines: 5,
          maxLines: 5,
        ),
```

Comment: The code you provided would be scrollable because you set `readOnly` to `true`, which as I mention on the question is not what I am looking for because it provides other UX issues and makes all the `TextFormField` disabled properties useless.

Comment: i think in flutter you wont be able to scroll when enable is false , only thing u can do is change UI accordingly for better user experience. may be some one knows better option.. hope you ill find better way